# Composition of Functions

Tags: python, function, lambda, printing

```
def thrice(f):
    return lambda x: f(f(f(x)))
print(thrice(thrice)(lambda x: x+3)(2))
print((thrice)(thrice)(lambda x: x+3)(2))
```

Both print statements give the answer 83, but I don't understand how the answers were derived. Can anybody enlighten me on the difference between the two?

Comment: You came from List language? If results are match, then the difference between number of parentheses

Comment: The only difference between the two is that the second one has a pair of meaningless extra parens around the first `thrice`. I'm not sure how to explain that any more deeply without dumping the AST or something, but it's pretty trivial.

Comment: What for an difference do you perceive? As abarnert said the paranthesis are superflous and both lines are the same.

Comment: I think there's actually a good question buried in here that you just didn't ask right. I tried to answer that question as well as the one you actually did ask. If you're still confused, let me know what's confusing and I can probably improve it.

Answer (score 3):

The only difference between the two is a pair of meaningless parentheses, so of course they give the same answer. It's the same as asking for the difference between these two:

```
math.abs(2)
(math.abs)(2)
```

Or, even better (thanks to Olivier Melançon for pointing this out), the difference between these two:

```
1 + 2
(1) + 2
```

Practically speaking, there is no difference. The first step in parsing them goes a bit differently, but they end up with the same AST, and therefore the same bytecode, and therefore the same behavior.

---

You may have instead wanted to ask about this:

```
>>> thrice(thrice(lambda x: x+3))(2)
29
>>> thrice(thrice)(lambda x: x+3)(2)
83
```

That's a big difference.

In the first one, we're calling `thrice` on the lambda, so it gives us a function that adds 3, then adds 3, then adds 3, so it adds 9. And then we call `thrice` on that, so it gives us a function that adds 9, then adds 9, then adds 9, so it adds 27. We then call that on 2, and of course get 29.

In the second one, we're calling `thrice` on `thrice`, so it gives us a function that triple-thrices, doing whatever we ask it to do 3**3 (27) times. We then call it on the lambda, so it adds 3, 37 times, which means it adds 81. And then we call that on 2, and get 83.

It might be less confusing if you apply `thrice` and `thrice(thrice)` to `lambda x: x+1` instead of `lambda x: x+3` so you don't get those separate 3's mixed up, and if you call the final function on 0 instead of 2.

---

With most functions, you can't confuse yourself by writing something like that—one version or the other will be a simple `TypeError`. (Try writing `math.fabs(math.fabs)`, or `int(int)` and see what happens.) What makes `thrice` so special?

Well, think about the type of `thrice`. You give it any function of type `A->A` (that is, it takes a value of some type `A` and returns a value of the same type `A`), and it returns another function of type `A->A`. But that means it is, itself, a function of type `A->A`, so you can call it on itself. This is one of those things that seems really mind-blowing until you think about the types, but it's nothing all that exciting once you do. ["No, John, you are the type theory!" And then John was a Haskell.](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/doom-repercussions-of-evil)

Comment: I would make it even clearer by pointing out that they are the same for the same reason `(1) + 1 == 1 + 1`, it is a parentheses that does not affect the order of operations, or in this case the order of parsing.